# SQL query to get the output in the format "YYYY/ MM" for first date of the year till now

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I want to create a query to get the below output

```
2022 / 01
2022 / 02
2022 / 03
2022 / 04
2022 / 05
2022 / 06
2022 / 07
2022 / 08
```

i.e. all months in above format till the current month

how to get tweak my query to get the above output

```
select  
    (To_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') || ' / ' || To_char(sysdate, 'mm'))
from dual
```

Comment: Did the answer from Alex Poole not work for you?  I just tried both queries and they appear to return the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html):

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), level - 1), 'YYYY/MM') as result
from dual
connect by level <= extract(month from sysdate)
```

`extract(month from sysdate)` gives you the current month number, which is 8, as the limit for the hierarchy. At each level the required number of months - `level - 1` - is added to the first day of the year.

Or you could use [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BCEJGIBG):

```
with rcte (month_start) as (
  select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
  from dual
  union all
  select month_start + interval '1' month
  from rcte
  where month_start < trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
)
select to_char(month_start, 'YYYY/MM') as result
from rcte
order by month_start
```

The anchor member gets the first day of the year. The recursive member adds a month to the previous result, until the start of the current month has been generated.

Both give the same result:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2022/01 |
| 2022/02 |
| 2022/03 |
| 2022/04 |
| 2022/05 |
| 2022/06 |
| 2022/07 |
| 2022/08 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8c1e5b8e8262e185167a12fd3e9c5454)